# AngularJs passing parameter to StateProvider

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

In an Mvc view I have:

```
<button ui-sref="edit({parameter1: 'value'})">
```

In the .js file:

```
    angular
    .module('caseApp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource', "kendo.directives"])
    .config(
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
        {
                $stateProvider
                    .state('edit',
                        {
                            url: '/Edit',
                            templateUrl: '/Clients/ClientEdit'
                        })
```

How can I take the value of the button's parameter parameter1 in .state in order to pass this parameter to the action /Clients/ClientEdit?

Comment: you don't have any parameters defined in the url. Likely need to read the router docs a bit more. WHat you are asking is all in the docs and in the examples

Comment: ok I have added the parameter in the url for precision.

Comment: but i meant in the route config. That param won;t do any good in `ui-sref` without it defined in the url. This is all well documented

Comment: You certainly must be right and I'll read the doc, but for what I need now mxa055 gave me the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a state param using this syntax:

```
ui-sref="edit({ myParameter: myValue})">
```

This will then be available in the edit state as a stateParam.

> Note: you need to define accepted parameters in the url beforehand
>   e.g.

```
.state('edit',
   {
       url: '/Edit?myParameter',
       templateUrl: '/Clients/ClientEdit'
   })
```

Now you can get this param by either injecting the $state or $stateParams service in your controller.

And if you want to load a different template depending on the state parameter passed you can use the template as a function syntax where your state definition would become:

```
.state('edit',
   {
       url: '/Edit?my_parameter',
       templateUrl: function($stateParams){
            return '/Clients/ClientEdit/' + $stateParams.myParameter;
       }
   })
```